Again with spring-boot-starter-parent (3.2.5) Rest-Template does not send content-Length
As discussed in Springboot 3.2.0 custom RestTemplate doesn't send Content-Length there was a problem regarding content-length with spring-boot 3.2.0.
As recommended in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#web-applications we used BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory. This works until upgrading from spring-boot-starter-parent from 3.2.4 to 3.2.5
We expect the content-length to be set.
We tried again with old version ( 3.2.4 ) - this still works.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

OK- the problem is discussed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32678

This should be a comment, not an answer.

This is fixed in spring-web v6.1.7, so you will need to add this dependency to your pom until A spring boot version is released with that version of spring-web
